Android Studio is not recognizing my JAVA_HOME
I am trying to integrate firebase_core into my flutter app. However I'm getting some issues, and I think it stems from using java 21, so I want to switch to java 17. I did all of the things necessary to do so. When I click run I get an error from Android studio saying that JAVA_HOME is set to invalid dir jdk-21.



My JAVA_HOME is set to jdk-17 and I am able to see that from my commandPrompt but not Android Studio. I invalidated caches, restarted and such, but it doesn't seem to work.

Reboot your machine.

I think it's probably sufficient to just restart AndroidStudio after the JAVA_HOME has been changed.
